# I am (US Permanent resident) Moving back to the UK for a year only and have Paper work questions

Tags: uk-citizens, family

I am moving to the UK for a year (for pleasure, not business). I currently live and plan to return to the US after that period, However my wife and son (US citizens) are coming with me and also plan to return home.

What paperwork must I fill out for myself and my family, I don't need Form I-131 as I won't be going past the 1 year time frame.

I am more concerned about my wife and son's travel documents both of which do not plan to work while in the UK.

Any information would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at the UK's site for information?  Also, are you certain your son is not a dual citizen?  If he is, he obviously won't need any paperwork other than proof of citizenship.  By my reading of the laws, he probably is.

Comment: What citizenships do you and your family have?

Comment: @StrongBad OP has a UK citizenship, and is a US permanent resident. Wife and son are both US citizens. Son might have UK citizenship as well.

Comment: Wife is US citizen and has a US passport also son too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wife will need a visa to stay for longer than six months.  It looks like you should start here for information: https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk.  The visa described on that page is rather costly: £956.

It looks like she could also go to the UK without a visa, and apply after she arrives.  That process is described here: https://www.gov.uk/remain-in-uk-family.  This is less expensive: £649 if you apply by post.

Your son is quite likely a British citizen, depending on *your* citizenship status and possibly on the reason you were in the US when he was born.  If your son is a British citizen, you should apply for a UK passport for him.  He will then need no other paperwork to live in the UK.  The passport fee is far lower than the visa fees (roughly £50 to £100 depending on your son's age and a couple of other factors; see https://www.gov.uk/passport-fees).

To check your son's citizenship, visit this site and enter your son's information: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen.

As US citizens, your wife and son will not need any paperwork to return to the US.